# Check to see if Array of Objects have >1 property values that !== undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var array = [
  {"name": "one", "value": .33},
  {"name": "one", "value": .54},
  {"name": "one", "value": undefined},

  {"name": "two", "value": .3},
  {"name": "two", "value": undefined},
  {"name": "two", "value": undefined},

  {"name": "three", "value": undefined},
  {"name": "three", "value": undefined},
  {"name": "three", "value": undefined},
];
```

And I need to be able to see if any unique name (one/two/three) has only one number among it's "value" properties. So, in this example the answer would be Yes because the value properties of "two" are: .3, undefined, undefined.

I do have a good way to get the unique "name" fields into an array:

```
function Names(a) {
  var temp = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    temp[a[i].name] = true;
  var r = [];
  for (var k in temp)
    r.push(k);
  return r;
}

nameArray = Names(array);
```

But when I start to look to actually do a loop I start to get confused. Just writing it out I'd think it would be like:

```
var count = 0;
for (objects with name == i){
  if (isNaN(value) == false){
    count++
    if(count > 1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, that is pseudo code and probably not even the right direction. Any help is appreciated, thanks for reading!

Comment: Well, first things first. Do you know how to check if a property of an object is `undefined`?

Comment: @crush Well, it may be the wrong approach, but I thought that I could just use 'isNaN(array[0].value)'

Comment: Well, technically, it would be "defined" if it had a value like `"test"`, but you probably mean, you want it to be a numeric value, rather than not undefined. Right?

Comment: And you want to basically be able to say `hasOnlyOneNumber(array, "two")`? Or did you want an array of all the entries that have only one number?

Comment: Yea, I do not need an array of the entries that only have one number, I just need to know that there is a "name" within the array that only has one number.

Comment: So, then `hasNameWithOnlyOneNumber(array)` it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create object with count of values that are numbers for each unique name and then check if count of any name is **1** with `some` and that will return `true/false`

```js
var array = [{"name":"one","value":0.33},{"name":"one","value":0.54},{"name":"one"},{"name":"two","value":0.3},{"name":"two"},{"name":"two"},{"name":"three"},{"name":"three"},{"name":"three"}], 
    obj = {}

array.forEach(function(e) {
  if(!obj[e.name]) obj[e.name] = 0;
  if(typeof e.value == 'number') obj[e.name]+=1;
});

var result = Object.keys(obj).some(e => { return obj[e] == 1});
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Only thing I'd change is the `if(typeof e.value == 'number')` because it doesn't handle numbers that are strings. Maybe that's not a requirement for him. In which case, you should at least use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: @crush I am not sure if i understood you correctly but i think this won't count numbers that are strings https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/931/ (i changed number to string in first object)

Comment: Your answer won't count numeric strings - which is what I was saying. However, the author never made it clear if he requires a check for numeric strings.

Comment: I see, in that case maybe OP can use something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/932/

Comment: Oh, @crush that is a good catch. In this instance I can be sure that the numbers will always just be normal numbers and not strings.

Comment: Something I realized after testing with this that most people probably know: Arrow functions will cause issues with some browsers (iOS, Safari, IE). You can adjust this answer by replacing the => line with: `var result = Object.keys(obj).some(function(e) { 
  return obj[e] == 1; 
});
`

Answer (score 3):

If you can't guarantee that they will be ordered by name in the array, then Nenad has the best answer.

If the order is guaranteed, though, you could write a function as follows:

```js
//Should be false
var array1 = [{"name":"one","value":0.33}];
//Should be false
var array2 = [{"name":"one","value":0.33},{"name":"one","value":0.54}];
//Should be false
var array3 = [{"name":"one","value":0.33},{"name":"one","value":0.54},{"name":"one","value":undefined}];
//Should be true - middle sequence contains one value
var array4 = [{"name":"one","value":0.33},{"name":"one","value":0.54},{"name":"one"},{"name":"two"},{"name":"two","value":0.3},{"name":"two"},{"name":"three"},{"name":"three"},{"name":"three"}];
//Should be true - last sequence contains one value
var array5 = [{"name":"one","value":0.33},{"name":"one","value":0.54},{"name":"one"},{"name":"two"},{"name":"two","value":0.3},{"name":"two", "value":0.3},{"name":"three"},{"name":"three"},{"name":"three","value":0.3}];

function containsUniqueValueForUniqueName(entry, index) {
  //So you can see in console how it short circuits the loop.
  console.log("Checking entry", entry);
  
  //If the value is a number, then increase the last count.
  if (!isNaN(entry.value)) {
    this.lastName = entry.name;
    this.lastCount += 1;
  }
  
  //When the lastName changes, or if its the last entry in the array, check if lastCount was 1. If yes, then exit true.
  if (this.lastName !== entry.name || index === array1.length - 1) {
    if (this.lastCount === 1)
      return true;
  
    //If its not 1, then we need to reset the count to 0.
    this.lastCount = 0;
  }
  
  return false;
}

var array1Result = array1.some(containsUniqueValueForUniqueName, {});
var array2Result = array2.some(containsUniqueValueForUniqueName, {});
var array3Result = array3.some(containsUniqueValueForUniqueName, {});
var array4Result = array4.some(containsUniqueValueForUniqueName, {});
var array5Result = array5.some(containsUniqueValueForUniqueName, {});

console.log('array1', array1Result);
console.log('array2', array2Result);
console.log('array3', array3Result);
console.log('array4', array4Result);
console.log('array5', array5Result);
```

This would exit the loop as soon as it encountered a consecutive set that just had 1 value number.

**On a very large array, could save you quite a few iterations.** Again, it requires your data is presorted by name. So, if you are getting it presorted from a web service or something like that, then I'd suggest using this answer.

Comment: I believe it would fail on `[{"name":"one","value":0.33}, {"name":"one","value":0.33}]`. The "is last item in an array and count is exactly one" condition should be checked after count increment.

Comment: @РоманПарадеев Good observation! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consider using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) (here's a [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/yihixebuqu/edit?html,js,console)):

```
var array = [
  {"name": "one", "value": 0.33},
  {"name": "one", "value": 0.54},
  {"name": "one", "value": undefined},

  {"name": "two", "value": 0.3},
  {"name": "two", "value": undefined},
  {"name": "two", "value": undefined},

  {"name": "three", "value": undefined},
  {"name": "three", "value": undefined},
  {"name": "three", "value": undefined},
];

// groups objects by the key `name`
array = _.groupBy(array, function(obj) {
  return obj.name;
});

// gets the counts for each `name` of `value` properties that are numbers
array = _.mapValues(array, function(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(obj) {
     return _.isNumber(obj.value);
  }).length;
});

console.log(array);
```

This will ouput:

```
{
  one: 2,
  three: 0,
  two: 1
}
```

This tells you that object with name `one` has 2 `value`s that are numbers, `three` has 0 `value`s that are numbers, and `two` has 1 `value` that is a number.